# How to build the v5.x Spring? How to import the v5.x Spring to IDEA?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I want to import the v5.x Spring to IDEA.

I follow the document `import-into-idea.md` to run the command `./gradlew cleanIdea :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`.

Then, it throws errors.

**How do I import the v5.x project to IDEA?**

I try many times at different ways:

1. I checkout the code to **v4.3.8.RELEASE**, I run the command `./gradlew cleanIdea :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`. It is OK.
2. I checkout the code to **v5.0.0.RC1**, I run the same command. It is OK. But, when I import the code to IDEA as a gradle project, the IDEA cound find many class, such as `BeanFactory`.
3. I run `./gradlew clean :spring-oxm:compileTestJava` (the code is v5.0.0.RC1), it throws many errors. **The command is `./gradlew clean :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`**

I report the question to Spring JIRA: [[SPR-15592] can not build the project. - Spring JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15592) . I watched the commit. The commiter changed the command from `./gradlew cleanIdea :spring-oxm:compileTestJava` to `./gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`. I tested the command, it still threw errors.

The way that I import the project to IDEA is as follows:

1. I run the command `./gradlew cleanIdea :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`
2. When Step 1 is OK, I open IDEA, click the **Import Project**  (Or File -> New -> Project from Existing Sources)
3. Choose the `spring-framework` folder
4. Choose `Import project from the external model` -> `Gradle`, Click `Next`
5. Click `Finish`, then wait some minutes.

> If the Step 1 threw errors, I import the code to IDEA, the IDEA cound find many classes, such as BeanFactory, I can not run the test method.

In this way, I can import the v4.* Spring to IDEA and can run the test methods. But I can not import the v5.* Spring to IDEA.

> If I first run the command `./gradlew clean` on the v5.x Spring, I run the command `./gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava` throw the errors.
>
> If the code is v4.x, it is OK.

My develop environment:

```
macOS 10.12.4

IDEA is 2017.1.3.

java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

**Don't care about IJ.** Please `git checkout master`, then `git pull`, get the latest sources. **First run `./gradlew clean`, then run `./gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`, later the errors should be thrown.**

The `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.test.FlightType`, `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.test.Flights` and `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.test.ObjectFactory` are imported into `Jaxb2MarshallerTests` and `Jaxb2UnmarshallerTests`. But I can not find the `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.test` package. I found the classes are configured in `/spring-oxm/src/test/resources/org/springframework/oxm/config/oxmNamespaceHandlerTest.xml`. **What mean the document is? How to generated the three classes?**

I found some confiuration about generating the test classes in `build.gradle`:

```
project("spring-oxm") {

...

    dependencies {

  ...

      testCompile("org.xmlunit:xmlunit-matchers:${xmlunitVersion}")
          testCompile(files(genCastor.classesDir).builtBy(genCastor))
          testCompile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))
      testRuntime("xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0")  // for Castor
      testRuntime("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:${jaxbVersion}")
      testRuntime("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:${jaxbVersion}")
    }
}
```

I guess the configurationg is used to generated the thress class. But I run `./gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`, it did not generated the thress class. **How to use the configuration?**

The error log is **[log is here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15592?focusedCommentId=152047&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-152047)**.

Comment: Which IntelliJ IDEA version are you using? If the command is OK before you open IJ and then is not after you open it, that is _very_ weird as this shouldn't make any difference. Super hard to track that without being able to reproduce.

Comment: IDEA is 2017.1.3. The commands were run in terminal. If I do not run `./gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`,  after I import to IDEA, I can not run the test methods.

Comment: The command is OK on the v4.x Spring. But it does not work on the v5.x.

Comment: On the v5.x, whether I open IJ, it always throws error.

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce any of that and I have no idea where that could come from. Try IJ 2017.2 EAP maybe

Comment: @StephaneNicoll Don't care about IJ. Please `git checkout master`, then `git pull`, get the latest sources. Please first run `./gradlew clean`, then run `./gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`, later you should see the errors.

Comment: I closed the issue because I obviously did that. This is the third time I am telling you I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145693/discussion-between-diguage-and-stephane-nicoll).

Answer (score 0):

I reclone the code from github. Then I can run `./gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`. I compare the two codes to find the differences.